# How can I open a new window not a new tab or popup window but a new fresh window in c# on button click from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I open a new window not a new tab or popup window but a new fresh window in c# on button click from code behind. I need to do this because popup blocker alwayz blocks my popup. Any help will be appreciated.

Like this:

http://epaper.greaterkashmir.com/epapermain.aspx

Comment: If you have a window opening on a user-generated click event it should not be stopped by a pop-up blocker.

Comment: http://epaper.greaterkashmir.com/epapermain.aspx see this website it has done it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant do from server but can do via javascript's window.open. For details see here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Please note that user can configure his/her browser to either block popup or open popup as new tab, in this scenario you will be out of luck.

If possible you can think of using modalpopup, styling it as a popup window.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything client side (opening browser Windows or similar) from the server side (C#) so the answer is "you can't".

Comment: I think nothing is impossible.

Comment: Then you think wrong, it's not impossible as in "it's hard", it's impossible by design, it's like asking "how do i make cheese, but i only have water", well you just don't, it's not possible.

Comment: Ronan see this website even if browser popup is blocked popup comes up without any problem...http://epaper.greaterkashmir.com/epapermain.aspx then say anything and think.

Comment: you can open using java script you have to inject client side script from server side to do this there is a mehtod in javascript window.open(url,width,height) which opens a new window